# Email Settings changes aren't saving

Tags: bug, email, profile-page

On the "Edit Email Settings" page, I currently have all email settings toggled to the on position, and want to turn some of them off. The changes do not seem to be saving, however, and every time I reload the page, the settings revert to "on".

[image: email settings]

Is the autosave feature broken?

This seems to only be a problem for the on/off toggles which call the subscribe/unsubscribe methods.

The Inbox setting which has four options instead of just on/off, and calls the update-inbox-frequency method, seems to work.

I do not see any errors in dev tools, and all the methods mentioned above return the same 204 status.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @JonClements When I click on one of the "off" buttons, all I see is that the unsubscribe method is called and it returns status 204. That is the only thing I see happening.

Comment: With that said, I am having the same issue as you are: my email settings are note saving. I opened up the inspector and no console messages are showing up when I toggle the inbox settings. Currently I am using firefox quantum in private browsing mode on ubuntu 17.04, not sure if this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the cause of this bug, but it seems to now be working.

If anyone from Stack Overflow wishes to give an official response, I'll gladly remove this answer, but for now, I'm creating this answer to indicate that the problem appears to be fixed.